# Ubuntu 20.04 how to get rid of the white/grey screen of death

Tags: kubuntu, kde

On 26/6, I rebooted after and at the request of an update. I ended up with a white screen of death with no useful error message. Since then I've been trying to fix it. I have:

- rolled back the updates
- reinstalled ubuntu-desktop
- installed Kubuntu desktop
- and umpteen other suggestions I found online.
  None worked. I had my data backed up but my concern is the amount of time it would take to rebuild the PC if I had to reinstall.

Today, in KDE, which still gives me the grey screen of death, I noticed the plasma option. I tried it and it works. I'd like to get back to the standard desktop. Any ideas? I can access tty where I had to try everything as there is no way to start aps not started on start up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a graphics error, try to enter without graphics mode. In grub edit the boot command of ubuntu nd the work `nomodeset` after the word `splash`.

With that set you can now debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I tried that but all that happened was I ended up at login but it was displaying identical screens on both displays. I did not see any debug info.

I'm happy using Plasma now and have installed timeshift for faster restore if problems strike again.